# Eclipse RCP - Strange behaviour using a Wizard

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I've got an Eclipse RCP application and a strange behaviour while using a wizard page. Following situation:

I've got a wizard page which is part of a multi-page-wizard. At this page I override the `createContent(...)` method to create my widgets, etc. After creating my widgets 2 private methods `addListeners()` and `init()` are called which initializes my widgets out of the model and add some listeners (e.g. a ModifyListener). The obscure behaviour is the following: When I first call `init()` and after that call `addListeners()` everything works fine. But if I do it the vice versa I got a NullPointerException in the `WizardDialog.updateButtons()` method which is part of RCP framework: There is a variable called `currentPage` as the following code excerpt shows. This variable causes the NPE mentioned above. If I do it the right way, the variable is correctly set.

`...
if (backButton != null) {
    backButton.setEnabled(currentPage.getPreviousPage() != null);
} 
...`

I don't get this behaviour. Can someony explain it to me? Within the 2 private methods mentioned above no framework-calls are done. Maybe it's some timing issue?

Best regards,
AnarchoEnte

Comment: If you add the listeners before `init` the modify listener will fire if you change the contents of the control in `init`. What do you do in the modify listener?

Comment: Within my modify listener I just call `wizard.getContainer().updateButtons();` which calls the WizardDialog-Method mentioned above. This call leads to my NPE

Comment: The WizardDialog is not ready to deal with updateButtons during the createContent call.

Comment: But the `addListeners()` and `init()` calls are within the `createContent()` call (last 2 steps at this call) and it works fine when I use the right call-order.

Comment: When you call init first the modify listener will not have been added when you initialise the control contents so no modify listener is fired during the createContents. The other way round the modify listener will fire and you get the error

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, now I think it's all clear :)